# How to format amount with two decimal places

Tags: python, sql

I am fetching the amount from a SQL DB there I have set the type with 2 decimal places.
But say if the amount is 100.00. The response that I get is 100.0
I want two zeros 100.00 as this is how UI is expecting.

How this can be done I am using python.

Comment: if your python is >3.8 then it can be done easily with f-strings. `f"{<float>:.2f}"` will return you stringified float with 2 decimal places

Comment: but this will convert int to string, is there a way that I can retain the int data type and do this?

Answer (score 0):

your python variable contain 100.0, but then can be formatted by UI itself or during cast to string *(transformation of your number variable to a string variable)*

In order to respond your answer, could you please share details like :

- how is build your UI
- code sample where you fetch your data
- code sample to shows/demonstrate your issue

Comment: UI build by some other folks they want this 100.00 in the API response.
Instead of amt=100.0 they want amt=100.00

Comment: how your api is returning data to front ?

Comment: as a response to post request in form of value in dictionary

Comment: plain text response or json formatted ? something like : my_string = "{:.2f}".format(my_float) and then return my_string instead